# missed $ while using variableName in bash script - how to catch such issues?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script which does the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
moduleName=$1
someInfo=`ls | grep -w moduleName`
echo $someInfo
```

In the line #3, I was supposed to use `$moduleName`, but I missed it.

Is there any way to find such issues in Bash scripts?

I used shell Check, but it didn't report this issue.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the script looks fine; it lists the files whose name contain the string `moduleName`.

The script is syntactically correct.
The error in line #3 is a semantic error; it changes the meaning of the script. Only a person that knows the intention of the script can detect it.

There is no way to automatically detect such errors, unless you write a software that reads your mind and knows that you intended to write `$moduleName` and you mistakenly wrote `moduleName` instead.

Comment: Thanks @axiac for edit and response. I am indeed looking for some semantic checker, but I think there is nothing that can help.